# Javascript function does not run after a function that I created

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a pretty simple and straight forward website. I have a table and a user can fill information in the `input="text"` fields. I add rows with the plus button that triggers the `insertRow()` function and remove rows with `removeRow()` function dynamically. The wipe button removes every text from `input="text"` fields. When I click the proceed button, the function `proceed()` is triggered which rebuilds the above table in a new one below. After the rebuild, I add the text from the fields and then, run the `removeButtons()` function to remove all the buttons from the right side of the tables.

The problem is that I run the `removeButtons()` inside the `proceed()` function but the `removeButtons()` does not get executed. I can not seem to find what is wrong even though I spend quite some time trying to solve the problem, that is why I am requesting help from people with much more experience than me. I know probably the problem is in the `proceed()` function but I tried several things from which none solved my problem.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <style>
    .btndiv {
      position: relative;
      top: -20px;
    }
    
    .btn {
      position: absolute;
      right: -30px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-image: url(minus.jpg);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btnPlus {
      position: absolute;
      right: -60px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-image: url(plus.jpg);
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .hideP {
      display: none;
    }
    
    table,
    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function insertRow() {
      //>>> Inserting a row and a div that holds the buttons on every last cell in each row
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      var count = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
      var row = table.insertRow(count);
      var cell = 0;
      while (cell <= 6) {
        var cl = row.insertCell(cell);
        cl.innerHTML = "<input type='text' />";
        if (cell == 6) {
          cl.innerHTML = "<input type='text' /><div class='btndiv'><div class='btn' onclick='deleteRow(this.id)'></div><div class='btnPlus' name='plus' onclick='insertRow()'></div></div>";
        }
        cell++;
      }
      hidePlus();
      resetIds();
    }

    function deleteRow(theId) {
      //>>> Deleting a row
      var count = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
      if (count == 3) {
        alert("The table must have at least one row!");
      } else {
        theId++;
        theId++;
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(theId);
        hidePlusDelete();
        resetIds();
      }
    }

    function resetIds() {
      //>>> Resetting the ids of my buttons dynamically (when inserting or removing row)
      var count = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
      var y = 0;
      var temp;
      while (y <= count) {
        temp = x[y];
        temp.setAttribute("id", y);
        y++;
      }
    }

    function hidePlus() {
      //>>> Hiding all plus buttons in every row except the last one on the right side of the minus button
      var count = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
      if (count > 3) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btnPlus");
        var xlength = x.length;
        var xlengthnew = xlength - 1;
        var y = 0;
        var temp;
        while (y < xlengthnew) {
          temp = x[y];
          temp.setAttribute("class", "hideP");
          y++;
        }
      }
    }

    function hidePlusDelete() {
      var count = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
      if (count >= 3) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hideP");
        var xlength = x.length;
        var xlengthnew = xlength - 1;
        var y = 0;
        var temp;
        if (y === xlengthnew && count < 3) {
          temp = x[y];
          temp.setAttribute("class", "btnPlus");
        }
      }
    }

    function clearTable() {
      //>>> Clear all input="text" fields
      var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for (var i in inp) {
        if (inp[i].type == "text") {
          inp[i].value = "";
        }
      }
    }

    function proceed() {
      //>>> Get text from text boxes and store them in the text variable
      //>>> Counter variable to get the number of input="text" fields
      var text = "";
      var count = 0;
      var inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var i in inp) {
        if (inp[i].type == "text") {
          text += inp[i].value;
          text += ";";
          count++;
        }
      }

      //>>> Store the HTML code from myTable in data variable
      //>>> Put the HTML code in newTable
      var data = document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("newTable").innerHTML = data;

      //>>> Splitting my text in parts
      //>>> Put the text in the input="text" of newTable
      var temp = 0;
      var counter = 0;
      var tempor;
      var temporary;
      var values = text.split(";");
      var p2inp = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for (var c in p2inp) {
        if (p2inp[c].type == "text") {
          temp = counter + count + 2;
          tempor = p2inp[temp];
          temporary = values[counter]
          tempor.value = temporary;
          //inp[temp].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
          //inp[temp].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
          counter++;
        }
      }

      //>>> Hiding buttons from the tables
      //>>> The buttons are divs modified to look like buttons with css
      removeButtons();
    }

    function removeButtons() {
      //>>> Adding the css class hideP (display="none")
      alert("in remove buttons");
      var divcount = document.getElementsByClassName("btndiv").length;
      alert(divcount);
      var divcounter = 0;
      var divtemp = 0;
      var divinp = document.getElementsByClassName("btndiv");
      while (divcounter <= divcount) {
        divtemp = divinp[divcounter];
        divtemp.setAttribute("class", "hideP");
        divcounter++;
      }
    }
    window.onload = insertRow;
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <table id="myTable" style="width: 50%">
    <col>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">Name, strength and form of medicine</th>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">What it's for</th>
      <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup">How much to take, when</th>
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">Extra instructions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Breakfast</th>
      <th scope="col">Midday meal</th>
      <th scope="col">Evening meal</th>
      <th scope="col">Bed Time</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br/>

  <input type="image" src="whipe.png" onclick="clearTable()" width="50px" height="50px" />
  <input type="image" src="go.png" onclick="proceed()" width="50px" height="50px" />

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <table id="newTable" style="width: 50%"></table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Always check the browser console for errors (press F12). I'm getting errors because both `temp` and `tempor` are undefined. Use `console.log(some_variable);` to debug your code.

Comment: @ChrisG - Or better yet, instead of stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, *turn on the lights* using the debugger built into the browser or IDE. :-)

Comment: @ ChristodoulosDemetriou - The collections the DOM provides you are 0-based, like arrays, so the valid indexes are `0` through `length - 1`. So for instance, on line 79 of that page, `while (y <= count) {` should be `while (y < count) {`. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (maybe) is this loop, if you comment it out, the desired function will run, so start search for an error here, or from the used variables in your loop:

```
for (var c in p2inp) {
            if (p2inp[c].type == "text") {
                temp = counter + count + 2;
                tempor = p2inp[temp];
                temporary = values[counter]
                tempor.value = temporary;
                //inp[temp].setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
                //inp[temp].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

And as others said, always check for errors in the console.
Also I recommend to try start to debug your javascript.